# How to return one record if all columns return null or return only non-null columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need a way to handle the following scenario.

Write a query to transform the following result set

```
ID|Location|NameA|ValueA|NameB|ValueB|NameC|ValueC|NameD|ValueD|
__|________|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|
0 |   BL   |NULL |NULL  |NULL |NULL  |NULL |NULL  |NULL |NULL  | 
__|________|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|
1 |   GT   |x    |y     |NULL |NULL  |s    |z     |NULL |NULL  |
__|________|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|
2 |   SZ   |c    |d     |e    |f     |NULL |NULL  |NULL |NULL  | 
__|________|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|_____|______|
```

...to this one

```
ID|Location|Name |Value |
__|________|_____|______|
0 |   BL   |NULL |NULL  |
__|________|_____|______|
1 |   GT   |x    |y     |
__|________|_____|______|
1 |   GT   |s    |z     |
__|________|_____|______|
2 |   SZ   |c    |d     |
 _|________|_____|______|
2 |   SZ   |e    |f     |
```

- For the records with all NULL "Name/Value" columns **I don't want four records** in the resulting table, I want only one.
- For the records with more than one NON-NULL Name/Value pairs I want them shown as separate records of the resulting table and NULL Name/Value pairs ignored.
- If for instance NameA is not null and ValueA is null, it's discarded from the resulting table, as per original scenario.

EDIT:
I decided to use your cross apply option, but have trouble implementing it,
I will paste my original query with table names changed so Gordon or someone else may help.

```
select t.CADID, t.TECHNOLOGYTYPE, t.ACCESSSUPPLIER, t.LOCATION, t.LOCATIONTYPE, t.NETWORKTYPE, t.ACCESSTYPE, t.CARRIERTYPE, t.MAXDOWNSPEED, t.MAXUPSPEED, v.NAME, v.VALUE 
from( TableA t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB VIEW0 ON (VIEW0.access_supplier = t.access_supplier
                                            AND VIEW0.network_type = t.network_type
                                            AND VIEW0.address_location_type_map_id = t.address_location_type_map_id
                                            AND VIEW0.NAME = 'Nls-type')
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB VIEW1 ON (VIEW1.access_supplier = t.access_supplier
                                           AND VIEW1.network_type = t.network_type
                                            AND VIEW1.address_location_type_map_id = t.address_location_type_map_id
                                            AND VIEW1.NAME = 'NL-type')
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB VIEW2 ON (VIEW2.access_supplier = t.access_supplier
                                            AND VIEW2.network_type = t.network_type
                                            AND VIEW2.address_location_type_map_id = t.address_location_type_map_id
                                            AND VIEW2.NAME = 'Net-type')
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB VIEW3 ON (VIEW3.access_supplier = t.access_supplier
                                            AND VIEW3.network_type = t.network_type
                                            AND VIEW3.address_location_type_map_id = t.address_location_type_map_id
                                            AND VIEW3.NAME = 'Interconnect-level')
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB VIEW4 ON (VIEW4.access_supplier = t.access_supplier
                                            AND VIEW4.network_type = t.network_type
                                            AND VIEW4.address_location_type_map_id = t.address_location_type_map_id
                                            AND VIEW4.NAME = 'FTU-type')
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB VIEW5 ON (VIEW5.access_supplier = t.access_supplier
                                            AND VIEW5.network_type = t.network_type
                                            AND VIEW5.address_location_type_map_id = t.address_location_type_map_id
                                            AND VIEW5.NAME = 'Area-type')
 )WHERE (t.cad_id = '237864868')
cross apply
     (values ('a', VIEW0.name as name0, VIEW0.value as vaue0),
             ('b', VIEW1.name as name1, VIEW1.valueb as value1),
             ('c', VIEW2.name as name2, VIEW2.valuec as value2),
             ('d', VIEW3.name as name3, VIEW3.valued as value3)
     ) v(which, name, value)
where v.name is not null or
      (v.which = 'a' and
       v.name0 is null and v.name1 is null and v.name2 is null and v.name3 is null
      );
```

Comment: Unpivot ? https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer in Oracle is probably:

```
select t.id, t.namea as name. t.valuea as valuea
from t
where t.namea is not null or 
      (t.namea is null and t.nameb is null and t.namec is null and t.named is null)
union all
select t.id, t.nameb as name. t.valueb as valuea
from t
where t.nameb is not null 
union all
select t.id, t.namec as name. t.valuec as valuea
from t
where t.namec is not null 
union all
select t.id, t.named as name. t.valued as valuea
from t
where t.named is not null ;
```

For some (probably absurd reason), I provided the answer below thinking the question was tagged SQL Server.  Oracle 12C supports lateral joins, so the below could be adapted for Oracle syntax.

I'm leaving the rest of the answer here.

```
select t.id, v.name, v.value
from t cross apply
     (values ('a', t.namea, t.valuea),
             ('b', t.nameb, t.valueb),
             ('c', t.namec, t.valuec),
             ('d', t.named, t.valued)
     ) v(which, name, value)
where v.name is not null or
      (v.which = 'a' and

      );
```

I like to unpivot using `cross apply`.  So the basic unpivot is:

```
select t.id, v.name, v.value
from t cross apply
     (values (t.namea, t.valuea), (t.nameb, t.valueb), (t.namec, t.valuec), (t.named, t.valued)
     ) v(name, value);
```

You then want a condition that `null` only appears once if it is *all* the values.  You can use window functions for this:

```
select id, name, value
from (select t.id, v.name, v.value,
             count(*) over (partition by t.id, v.name, v.value) as cnt_nv,
             row_number() over (order by t.id) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (t.namea, t.valuea), (t.nameb, t.valueb), (t.namec, t.valuec), (t.named, t.valued)
           ) v(name, value)
     ) v
where name is not null or
      (cnt_nv = 4 and seqnum = 1);
```

I'm a little unclear if you just care whether `name` is `NULL` or whether you want both `name` and `value` to be `NULL`.  Either logic can be implemented; it is just unclear which you want.

EDIT:

You can also do this without a subquery:

```
select t.id, v.name, v.value
from t cross apply
     (values ('a', t.namea, t.valuea),
             ('b', t.nameb, t.valueb),
             ('c', t.namec, t.valuec),
             ('d', t.named, t.valued)
     ) v(which, name, value)
where v.name is not null or
      (v.which = 'a' and
       t.namea is null and t.nameb is null and t.namec is null and t.named is null
      );
```

This is probably the simplest way to write the logic.

Comment: I failed to notice your answer, will give it a try now.
And to answer your question, in the original query VALUE will never be null, so I only care whether all NAME/VALUE columns in one record are null, to return one NULL record and not the one for each NAME/VALUE pair.
I am having issues because of a complex original query I have, which is making this a bit hard.

Comment: @T_Dejan . . . For some reason, the original answer was for SQL Server (obviously I misread or ignored the tags on the question).  I've provided an Oracle-compatible answer.

Comment: Can you take a look, I edited the question.
I tried with the subquery and cross apply option but am having trouble implementing.
Is this possible in Oracle?

Comment: @T_Dejan . . . Create a CTE with your query (`with t as ( . . . )`), then use the first version with `union all`.

Comment: @T_Dejan . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?  What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `UNPIVOT` as follows:

```
-- Sample Data:
WITH dat(ID,Location,NameA,ValueA,NameB,ValueB,NameC,ValueC,NameD,ValueD) AS
  (SELECT 0 ,   'BL'   ,NULL ,NULL  ,NULL ,NULL,NULL ,NULL,NULL ,NULL  FROM dual
    UNION
   SELECT 1 ,   'GT'   ,'x'  ,'y'   ,NULL ,NULL,'s'  , 'z',NULL ,NULL  FROM dual
    UNION
   SELECT 2 ,   'SZ'   ,'c'  ,'d'   ,'e'  ,'f' ,NULL ,NULL,NULL ,NULL  FROM dual)
-- SQL-Statement:
SELECT id,location, NAME, VALUE 
  FROM (
    SELECT id,location, NAME, VALUE,sk, MAX(NAME) over (PARTITION BY id) max_name
      FROM dat
      UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS(
        (NAME, VALUE) FOR sk IN ((NameA, ValueA) AS 1
                                ,(NameB, ValueB) AS 2
                                ,(NameC, ValueC) AS 3
                                ,(NameD, ValueD) AS 4)
      )
)
WHERE (SK = 1 AND max_name IS NULL)
   OR NAME IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UNION`, as below:

```
select ID,Location,NameA,ValueA from table where NameA is not null
union
select ID,Location,NameB,ValueB from table where NameB is not null
union
select ID,Location,NameC,ValueC from table where NameC is not null
union
select ID,Location,NameD,ValueD from table where NameD is not null
union
select ID,Location,null,null from table where coalesce(NameA,NameB,NameC,NameD) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tempTbl table ([ID] int, [Location] nvarchar(10), [Name] nvarchar(10), [Value] nvarchar(10));
insert into  @tempTbl 
 select  [ID],[Location],[Name], [Value] From
(
SELECT [ID],[Location],[NameA] as [Name],[ValueA] as [Value] FROM [dbo].[LocationTbl]
    UNION 
    SELECT [ID],[Location],[NameB],[ValueB] FROM [dbo].[LocationTbl]
    UNION 
    SELECT [ID],[Location],[NameC],[ValueC] FROM [dbo].[LocationTbl]
    UNION 
    SELECT [ID],[Location],[NameD],[ValueD] FROM [dbo].[LocationTbl]
) as X
where [Name] is not null AND [Value] is not null
select * from @tempTbl
UNION
SELECT [ID], [Location], Null as [Name], Null as [Value]
FROM [dbo].[LocationTbl]
WHERE  [Location] not in (select [Location] from @tempTbl)
order by [ID];
```

try this.